# C++ - Help Interpreting the instructions of a CRC error-checking programming assignment

Tags: c, c++, error-correction, crc, parity

This is unconventional, based on what I've seen, but I can't get a hold of my professor's aides to clarify this assignment. I hope this is still ok to post here.

I would greatly appreciate some help from you folks in interpreting the instructions for a programming assignment I've been given, related to parity bits and CRC error checking. I would like help with the logic behind the instructions, and some guidance on what the processes that are named in the instructions are meant to do. Once I understand the logic, I (at least hope) plan to be able to take care of the actual programming portion myself from there.

I feel the instructions are not very concise (though they may be just fine to those familiar with the material). Phrases I am especially perplexed by will be in ***bold+italics***:

> **Error Detection and Coding: Parity, CRC & FEC**
>
> **Part 1:**
>
> a) Write a program (in any language, such as C, C++, Java, Javascript,
>   or Python) that generates a parity bit (***even or odd - you choose***) for
>   each byte of data and verify its correct operation.
>
> b) Write another program to ***detect correct data based on the parity***
>   you have defined. Then use the program to generate a byte of data
>   along with the parity bit (9-bits total), and observe ***what happens
>   when there are 0, 1, 2, or 3 bits in error*** in a given byte. Include a
>   screenshot of the results (command line or other) and discuss the
>   ***probability of an undetected error*** occurring.
>
> **Part 2:**
>
> a) Write a program that generates an ***8-bit CRC checksum*** for a data
>   stream. An example of this program follows, in pseudocode. This same
>   program may be used to check correct reception of the data stream. The
>   simplest data stream for which this may be used is two bytes; simulate
>   at least 5 different ***2-byte data streams both with and without errors***
>   and log the results. Particularly interesting are error data streams
>   which differ by only 1 bit from the correct data.
>
> b) Also, simulate at least one 32-byte data stream with at least one
>   error and log the results. Include a screenshot of the results and
>   discuss the probability of an undetected error occurring.

**CRC Program Pseudocode**

```
Initialize counter and data stream
Loop for each bit in data stream
Define next states for each bit
Next Bit 1 = next bit of Data In
Next Bit 2 = Present Bit 1
Next Bit 3 = Present Bit 2 XOR
present Bit 8
Next Bit 4 = Present Bit 3 XOR
present Bit 8
Next Bit 5 = Present Bit 4 XOR
present Bit 8
Next Bit 6 = Present Bit 5
Next Bit 7 = Present Bit 6
Next Bit 8 = Present Bit 7
Move next states into present states
Present Bit 1 = Next Bit 1
Present Bit 2 = Next Bit 2
Present Bit 3 = Next Bit 3
Present Bit 4 = Next Bit 4
Present Bit 5 = Next Bit 5
Present Bit 6 = Next Bit 6
Present Bit 7 = Next Bit 7
Present Bit 8 = Next Bit 8
Output CRC encoder byte to screen
End loop
Output final CRC checksum byte
```

***Bold+Italics Portions***:

**1a)**

- I'm creating a function through which I manually type out a byte, in order to test my program. Correct?
- "***even or odd - you choose***" - I know a *byte* is a string of 8 bits, each of which is either a **1** or a **0**. I know a *parity bit* is a "9th bit" tacked at the end of the bit sequence. I think "even or odd - you choose" means that I should decide whether a **1** parity bit indicates that there is an *even* number of **1**'s in the byte or that there is an *odd* number of **1**'s in the byte. Correct?

**1b)**

- I'm now creating a byte generator that - based on whether there are an even or odd # of **1**'s in the generated byte - tacks on a *parity bit*, being a **1** or a **0**. *(Let's just decide now that an even number of **1**'s means the parity bit will be **1**, and vice versa)*. Is this correct?
- "***detect correct data based on the parity***" - So...Just confirm that I have the correct number of **1**'s in my byte, based on the parity bit's value? Isn't that the same thing as "verify[ing] its correct operation" from step **a)**? What bytes are we using to do this step? We haven't created our byte generator yet. We were already asked to "verify [the parity bit's] correct operation" in step **a)**, so is this step redundant?
- "***what happens when there are 0, 1, 2, or 3 bits in error***" - Wait. So am I to *intentionally* create a byte generator that contains errors in some of the generated bytes? How would I even know that a generated byte *has* an error in it? I have no "base case" or "correct version of the byte" to compare each byte to. Who's to say that there's an error in it?
- ***probability of an undetected error*** - We're dealing with 1 byte, or 8 bits. I found [this page](http://sce.uhcl.edu/goodwin/Ceng5334/downLoads/ch2_new.pdf) that states the probability of an undetected error in 8-bit systems is \$P_{ue} = 1 - (1 - q)^8\$. Is this correct, standard equation that's used? Would the probability in a 16-bit system just be \$P_{ue} = 1 - (1 - q)^{16}\$?

**2a)**

***8-bit CRC checksum*** - So I need to write a function that generates a sequence of XOR gates at random positions in the 8-bit sequence? Based on the image below?:

[image]

I assume there can't be 0 XOR gates and there can't be XOR gates at all 8 bits. Are there any other limitations to generating a CRC checksum? So if the 8-bit Encoder looked like above, would the checksum be **01110000**? What do I do with the checksum?

***2-byte data streams both with and without errors*** - 2 bytes is 16 bits. Are we using the checksum generator in this step? Am I supposed to program the checksum generator to occasionally make mistakes? In this case, an "error" would be a byte that passes through the CRC encoder and ends up with a **1** where there should be a **0** or vice versa. Correct? I'm supposed to program it so the XOR gates/CRC encoder don't always do their job?

Comment: I hope your teacher also lets you know that parity checks is a horrible, unprofessional way of looking for any form of errors and that you should never use such crap in real-world applications. Particularly not as part of UART communication.

Answer (score 2):

To go through in order, and not answer specifically for homework purposes.

**1a** I wouldn't manually type out a byte stream, but it's easy to write a script to generate a nice selection of known values. Regards a parity bit, yes, you are correct.

**1b** You've started right. It's not redundant, as **1a** was to write a script that generated a parity bit, and **1b** is to write a script that checks the parity bit. You need to make a known byte stream that is correct, and then you can randomly flip some bits and see if the parity checker indicates a fault. Obviously you need to track if you flipped a bit. You can do the question parts.

**2** You need to read a little bit more about checksums, but again you're on the correct lines. The errors in the byte stream refer to corrupted transfers, not errors in the CRC system.